# gmail showing wrong time and timezone in calender invite section

Tags: calendar, timezone, gmail

My Gmail showing the wrong time and timezone in the calendar invite section
I am doing Microsoft Booking ,where invite mail comes after the booking confirmed

But only in the invite section time and timezone setting is not showing the right combination

Sat, 30 Sep 2023  04:30 AM - 04:45 AM  (UTC-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada) - this is correct

But Sat Sep 30, 2023 4:30am – 4:45am (IST) - this is incorrect in the calender invite section

[image]

If I change the calendar timezone from Gmail -> calendar fro IST to "America/Chicago"
still, then time shows incorrectly in calender invite section
please suggest where can i fix this.

This is an invite file generated (.ics file )

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:PUBLISH
PRODID:Microsoft Exchange Server 2010
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Central Standard Time
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:16010101T000000
TZOFFSETFROM:+0530
TZOFFSETTO:+0530
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:16010101T000000
TZOFFSETFROM:+0530
TZOFFSETTO:+0530
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
ORGANIZER;CN=XXXXXX:mailto:XXXXXX
DTSTAMP:20230927T054112Z
DTSTART;TZID=Central Standard Time:20230930T043000
DTEND;TZID=Central Standard Time:20230930T044500
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-US:XXXXXX
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=FALSE;CN=XXXXXX
UID:
SEQUENCE:1
CLASS:PUBLIC
PRIORITY:5
TRANSP:OPAQUE
STATUS:CONFIRMED
LOCATION;LANGUAGE=en-US:
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-APPT-SEQUENCE:3
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-OWNERAPPTID:
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:TENTATIVE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INTENDEDSTATUS:BUSY
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-ALLDAYEVENT:FALSE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INSTTYPE:0
X-MICROSOFT-ONLINEMEETINGINFORMATION:
X-MICROSOFT-SKYPETEAMSMEETINGURL:
X-MICROSOFT-SCHEDULINGSERVICEUPDATEURL:
X-MICROSOFT-SKYPETEAMSPROPERTIES:
X-MICROSOFT-DONOTFORWARDMEETING:FALSE
X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:TRUE
X-MICROSOFT-LOCATIONDISPLAYNAME:
X-MICROSOFT-LOCATIONSOURCE:
X-MICROSOFT-LOCATIONS:
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER;RELATED=START:-PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Reminder
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```